# How not to use a label when updating the database

Tags: asp.net

I get some data from the database that I want to use to update another Database row.

I know how to do that if I put the first value on a label and then use that.

//First I get the Name I want

```
DataTable table = GetName();
NameList.DataSource = table;
NameList.DataBind();


<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
```

But how do I do that whitout using a label like this.

//And then I want to add the name to another datarow

```
protected void btnName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = lblName.text;

    if (CategoryAccess.AddName(Name) != 0)
}
```

I Want to change the `lblName.Text` to something better then the label. Because I dont need the label. I just need the value that the label has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local variable:

```
DataTable table = GetName();
string firstName = string.Empty;
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
   firstName = table.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
```

After this code, the variable `firstName` will hold the same value that the Label you mentioned holds.